# C# Simple garbage collection code not working

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a simple WPF application that allocates memory, clears it, and interacts with the garbage collector. Unfortunately I can't ever see the garbage collected automatically clear memory. For example, say I click Alloc button 10 times it allocates a gig, then if I click the New button the allocated memory does not go down. However if I force a garbage collection with GC.Collect (GC button) it does free the memory. I have enabled large collections with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects set to true, as I would like to test with more than 2 gigs of use. Any idea how I can get the garbage collector to automatically collect and free the memory?

Simple code excerpt:

```
List<byte[]> m_allocs = new List<byte[]>();

private void AllocClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  int oneHundredMegsAsBytes = 100000000;
  byte[] array = new byte[oneHundredMegsAsBytes];
  Array.Clear(array, 0, oneHundredMegsAsBytes);
  m_allocs.Add(array);
}

private void NewClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  m_allocs = new List<byte[]>();
}

private void ClearClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  m_allocs.Clear();
}

private void GCClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: If the OS still has plenty of memory free, the GC tries not to run, because it doesn't need to. However, `Array.Clear()` in your sample is doing nothing - it just sets the contents of the array to the default value for the array element type; in your case, zero - but the array already contains all zeroes. It doesn't change the size of the array.

Comment: Garbage collection happens *at some unspecified point in time*, or possibly never if there's sufficient memory. It does not *eagerly* deallocate memory at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: And, bear in mind that the whole reason for there being a GC is to allow developers to not worry about managing memory. You don't need to test the GC, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When experimenting based on the new information from your comments I found a solution. If I press alloc a lot of times, eg till 10 gig use, then click clear and continue allocating more, it eventually drops down the memory usage down to a lower value, eg 2 gig.

So the garbage collector is automatically running with the sample code, it just works when memory usage is higher than what I was testing with and further allocations help.

Answer (score 3):

**You don't.**

The GC has been developed to only run when needed. If yours isn't running, then it doesn't need to.

**You don't want it to.**

GC is expensive, the GC has to stop the program and figure out what is and isn't needed. If it did this at the end of every cycle your program would grind to a crawl.

**However...**

You could change [the high-memory percent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#high-memory-percent) to a lower value, which will make the GC get much more aggressive, much earlier. **This will probably do you more harm than good**.